# error while querying tooling api for FullName EVEN WHEN LIMITED TO ONE RESULT

Tags: soql, query, tooling-api

I've been using the tooling API to query layouts and I need to access the metadata or FullName fields.
I know I can only use this with a single row at a time, so I either loop over all layouts with a "where Id='", or using an offset with a limit of 1.
So a query looks like this in python:

```
for index, id in enumerate(layout_ids):
    result = tooling.anon_query("select Id, Name, FullName
                                 from Layout
                                 Limit 1 Offset <index>")
```

Most of the time there is no problem, but once in a while I get this response:

```
"Entity 'CssDetail' not found.", 'errorCode': 'FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION'
```

It doesn't happen if I remove the Metata and FullName fields from the query, and it only happens for certain layouts (I use "try:... except:..." clauses and the error seems to affect about 20% of the queries, in random rows (not just in the beginning or end).
Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: does the error only occur with using the `limit 1` or does it also occur when querying with `where Id = 'layoutId'`?

Comment: It happens on both occasions